# Float / Array error reading from CSV

Tags: arrays, csv, processing

I'm missing something fundamental here but I can't seem to find out what from all my research.

I have imported a csv file, split the string into floats, and now wish to connect all points to all other points with a line. My code is as follows:

```
String [] data;


void setup () {
size(300, 300);
background(255);

data = loadStrings("points.csv");

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

String [] fields = split(data[i], ',');

float t = float(fields[0]);
float n = float(fields[1]);
float x = float(fields[2]);
float y = float(fields[3]);

ellipse(x, y, 10, 10);

line(x, y, x[i], y[i]);
}
}
```

The error message is "The type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to float"

I'm sure this is extremely basic but, I dont understand why x[i] or y[i] are not seen as an array type.

I would really appreciate any help with this. Many thanks in advance.

Sam

****UPDATE******

An exract from the points.csv file is as follows:

```
219185750   rabih_takkoush  20.88521    19.49821
219185716   MoustaphaAjram  100.870896  59.515259
219185709   jinanejghosh    56.886441   35.489087
219185557   MoustaphaAjram  34.870904   78.515243
219185555   Mohammad8Itani  12.8946         49.48179
```

What I am trying to accomplish is plotting the various geolocations (whereby col 3 = x, col 4 = y) and then connecting all points with all other points with a line.

The following script works plotting all locations specified in the array within the script:

```
float[] x = { 50, 100, 150, 200,20,20 };
float[] y = { 10, 30, 20, 250,20,90 };

void setup () {

size(300, 300);
background(255);
}


void draw() {

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
ellipse(x[i], y[i], 10, 10);

for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
line(x[j], y[j], x[i], y[i]);
}
}
}
```

What I wish to do is do the same, but reading columns 3 and 4 of the csv file.

Comment: They are not arrays that's why. see your declaration `float x`, if you wanted an array type you'd need to declare it as `float[] x`. btw why do you want them to be arrays? How is your csv looking?

Comment: i was under the understanding this was the correct way to extract data from csv's?

my orginal code is 

float[] x = {
  50, 100, 150, 200,20,20
};
float[] y = {
  10, 30, 20, 250,20,90
};

void setup () {
  size(300, 300);
  background(255);
}


void draw() {

  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    ellipse(x[i], y[i], 10, 10);
    
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    line(x[j], y[j], x[i], y[i]);
    }
  }
}

which works fine. if you know another way of inputing values from a csv file to this that would be fantastic. thanks for the help

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to accomplish exactly with this code please? Also add a sample from your csv file? And what does `t` and `n` stand for? Cuz well I can answer why you get the error you mention in your question, but that doesn't solve your problem, and right now I don't see clearly what you want to do so I need more information to help you. And btw you should edit your question when you add information about it, it's better (what you posted in your precedent comment adds more clarity to your question so it should be in it)

Comment: thanks for your comments, i've updated the question above. I hope this helps to understand what im trying to achieve. let me know if not!

Comment: yep it helped me a lot to understand what you wanted to do, I posted my answer (sorry quite a long time after your comment, wasn't in front of my computer for a moment)

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting your data into iteration-scoped floats, then you try to access them as if they're both floats as well as arrays in your line() call. Try this:

```
String[] data;
float[] x, y, t, n;

void setup () {
  size(300, 300);
  data = loadStrings("points.csv");
  int len = data.length;
  x = new float[len];
  x = new float[len];
  t = new float[len];
  n = new float[len];
  for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    String line = data[i];
    String[] fields = split(line, ',');
    t[i] = float(fields[0]),
    n[i] = float(fields[1]),
    x[i] = float(fields[2]),
    y[i] = float(fields[3]);
  }
  // don't put draw instructions in setup,
  // put them in draw. if you want to run once,
  // issue a noLoop() so that happens.
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  float prevx = x[0], prevy = y[0];
  for (int i=0, last=x.length; i<last; i++) {
    ellipse(x[i], y[i], 10, 10);
    line(prevx,prevy, x[i],y[i]);
    prevx=x[i];
    prevy=y[i];
  }
}
```

Now we're storing the data from CVS in linked arrays that we can access throughout the sketch, rather than throwing them away after setup().

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. 

these alterations are returning the error "The method line(float,float,float,float) in the type Applet is not applicable for the arguments (float, float, float[], float[])"

at line(prevx,prevy, x,y);

Answer (score 0):

ok so if you go with the first code you made, you only need to change a few things, here is what you can do:

```
float[] x;
float[] y;
string[] data;

void setup () {
   size(300, 300);
   background(255);

   data = loadStrings("points.csv");
   x = new float[data.length];
   y = new float[data.length];

   for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      String [] fields = split(data[i], ',');

      float t = float(fields[0]);
      float n = float(fields[1]);
      float x = float(fields[2]);
      float y = float(fields[3]);
   }
}


void draw() {

   for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      ellipse(x[i], y[i], 10, 10);

      for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
         line(x[j], y[j], x[i], y[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see nothing really new, it's a mix between your initial code and the one you made for the csv.
And actually you mainly needed to declare your `x` and `y` variables as `float[]` instead of just `float`. But also there were some changes to make in the loop.

In this code you load the data in your arrays first (exactly like you did by declaring array's values in your code, but this time you read these values from your file), and then call your draw method as before.

hope it works now

Comment: fantastic, thank you very much for your help

here what you helped me to achieve!

http://www.samcox.me/img/output.jpg

Comment: looks nice, congratulations ;)! btw the code I posted is really close to what Mike posted, so you should give him a "+1" (you can use the arrows on the left of each answer), and also if you think your question got an answer useful enough, you should mark it as answered (that's the way this website works)